# Place element right under navigation bar on scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation

If I have an element in a scroll view(not positioned in the top) how would I be able to let this element stay right under the navigation bar when it hits the bar on scroll ? Like the shuffle bar in the spotify app ?

Comment: Have you considered `UITableView`? Header views can be manipulated to work in such a way.

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: You mean , that I'm able to put a view inside my table header ? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your ScrollView delegate:

1. Implement `viewDidScroll:`
2. Check the offset of the scroll view in this method: adjust the position of your nav bar using the negative offset of the scrollview: `self.navBar.frame.origin.y = - view.yOffset;`

Comment: I think I have a hard time understanding what you mean . The navigation bar has to stay in place all the time . I want the element that hits the navigation bar to stay in place right under the bar . If your solution still makes sense, can you give me a short example?

Comment: When you scroll, all the scroll view does is move the content view relatively to the parent view, and adjusts the offset accordingly. For example, if you scroll down 10px, the offsetY of the scroll view will be -10px, then you can use this measurement to reposition your nav bar. That way the nav bar will always appear at the same place on the screen, but will actually be continuously moving on the scroll view's content view.

Comment: Checkout the Overview of the class reference if you don't understand what the offset is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html